# Mac Mail reply on letter format

Tags: macos, email

Good day, everyone :)
So I moved from Windows laptop to Macbook and I have a question. I have lot of people using Windows as a main OS and Outlook as a primary mail client. And when I was replying on letters using Outlook I am seeing such format:

```
**From**: James James <asdf@mailcom.com>
**Date**: Fri, 5 Sep 2014 15:07:08 -0500
**To**: Batman <batman@batworld.com>, Spiderman Spider <spiderman@marvell.com>
**Cc**: Joker <joker@batworld.com>
**Subject**: We are saving our world
Message text
Signature
```

Now I am using mac Mail client and when I am replying on someones letter it has format below:

```
//Space for message body
Signature
On Sep, 8, 2014, at 15:07:08, Somebody <somebody@asdf.com> wrote:
//full Thread.
```

How do I avoid that? So after I click on reply button I what to see:

```
//Space for message body
Signature

**From**: James James <asdf@mailcom.com>
**Date**: Fri, 5 Sep 2014 15:07:08 -0500
**To**: Batman <batman@batworld.com>, Spiderman Spider <spiderman@marvell.com>
**Cc**: Joker <joker@batworld.com>
**Subject**: We are saving our world
//full Thread
Signature
```

Comment: This question is probably off-topic for StackOverflow but you might want to check out [AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com), a StackOverflow-esque Q&A for Mac and Apple users.

Comment: I am sorry, for asking off-topic question.. I checked AskDifferent and I found question to my problem. Thank you, @wjl.
https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/49256/replywithheader solved my problem

Comment: Since you arrived at an answer, it wouldn't hurt for you to link to that article and put a little blurb about it as an answer to this question. Then you can accept your own answer and anyone who searches here (or finds this through Google) can see your answer more prominently.